# Not getting the jenkins unlock path

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops

Here I should get a path to unlock Jenkins while connecting with the  aws instance ip address. But I am getting like admin login. Is there any another way to get a password to unlock Jenkins.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can login to jenkins machine and check at `/var/lib/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

`/var/lib/jenkins` or whatever your `$HOME` is for `jenkins` user in `jenkins` instance